# How do I know, whether I need to run BibTeX or not?

Tags: bibtex, automation

If I have an unknown `*.tex` file and want to know, whether I need to run BiBTeX afterwards or not, what is the simplest way to find out in a script?

Consider this file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Test\cite{Test}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Mit}
\end{document}
```

compared to this file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

As far as I see the simplest way is to check the `*.aux` file:

```
\relax 
\citation{Test}
\bibdata{Mit}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

And if this contains a `\bibdata`, I need to run BibTeX, is that correct?

Comment: well your first example is incomplete at the bibliography style is missing, but apart from this looking for bibdata should be ok.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer, I added the missing `\bibliographystyle{plain}` line and will then just scan the `*.aux` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The `\bibliography` directive is a dead give-away that you'll need to run BibTeX at some point.
- Of course, BibTeX won't know *how* to format the bibliographic entries unless your document also contains a `\bibliographystyle` directive.
- Almost as diagnostic as the presence of `\bibliography` and/or `\bibliographystyle` would be the fact that your document loads a citation management package such as `cite`, `natbib`, or `apacite`.
- On the other hand, if your document loads the `biblatex` package, you should almost certainly *not* be running BibTeX and, instead, be running `biber`. The sole exception to this rule is if the `biblatex` package is loaded with the option `backend=bibtex`, in which case you'll definitely need to run BibTeX, not `biber`.

Comment: So you would recommend sticking with the original tex-file and scan it for bibliography or bibliographystyle commands, not the aux file?

Comment: @TobiBS - To my mind, the issue is that the aux file can get corrupted for any number of reasons (e.g., syntax errors). Depending on the nature of the error, LaTeX might not get a chance to write bibliography-related information to the aux file, possibly leading you to infer that there's no need to run BibTeX. Of course, if there are no errors, the aux file should eventually contain the relevant pointers to the bib file(s), the bib style, and all `\cite` directives. For sure, though, the tex file will *always* let you know whether or not you'll need to run BibTeX.

Answer (score 1):

I am interpreting your question as "how do I find out if a given arbitrary LaTeX document needs the `bibtex` run or not for a complete compilation".

That's the neat part, you don't (R). At least, you do not need to decide on this yourself. That's because there are quite a few LaTeX wrappers, that do exactly that.

I'd recommend `latexmk`. There is also `arara`, but I did not look into it. With `latexmk` you simply say:

- `latexmk -pdf document.tex`, it returns when all the steps of iterating `pdflatex` calls (and what also not, including `bibtex`) are done.
- as a further example, `latexmk -pdflua document.tex` requests LuaTeX with PDF output.

The `latexmk` script needs `perl`, so search for alternatives if this is a deal breaker. I am not sure, how well it works under Windows.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for your answer, which I also upvoted, but cannot accept. Of course latexmk does the job that I want to do, but in my current situation a move towards latexmk would require way more work than to decide whether I need to run BiBTeX or not. Hence I will take it into account for a future rework of the script, but not for now.